# perl -n with input from pipe and @ARGV

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I've got a one-liner like this:

```
date +%H | perl -ne 'printf "%02d", $_ - ($ARGV[0] - 1);' 1
```

It says:

```
Can't open 1: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
```

The error message means "File or directory not found".

I want it to take both the output from date and the commandline argument at the same time.

Essentially it should get me the current hour minus the argument minus one. If there are better ways to achieve this, I'll happily accept them. I'd still be grateful about an explanation as to why this doesn't work.

Let's assume it's after 10am now.

```
Param Output
    1     10
    2     09
    3     08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result might be yesterday or even further back in the past, it does not make much sense to print just the hour.

```
perl -mDateTime -e'
    my $dt = DateTime->now;
    $dt->subtract(hours => 1);
    $dt->subtract(hours => shift @ARGV);
    print $dt->hour;
' 4
```

Whereever possible, use a standard datetimestamp, such as RFC3339 which is in wide use.

```
perl -mDateTime -mDateTime::Format::RFC3339 -e'
    my $dt = DateTime->now;
    $dt->subtract(hours => 1);
    $dt->subtract(hours => shift @ARGV);
    print DateTime::Format::RFC3339->new->format_datetime($dt);
' 4
```

---

Your Perl one-liner deparses to:

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    printf '%02d', $_ - ($ARGV[0] - 1);
}
```

… because of [`-n`](http://p3rl.org/run#%2a-n%2a). [`ARGV`](http://p3rl.org/var#ARGV):

> The special filehandle that iterates over command-line filenames in @ARGV.

But you have no filenames as arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I need it to name a log analysis output file in a shell script. Depending on the time the script runs it uses lines from the original log file that are a variable amount of hours in the past. Because of the way it is called the date will not be yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

`perl -n` creates an implicit loop reading files listed as arguments or STDIN if there are no arguments; this conflicts with your use of an argument for something different.  You can fix it by clearing `@ARGV` in a BEGIN block:

```
date +%H | perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $arg=shift } printf "%02d", $_ - ($arg - 1);' 1
```

but for this particular task, you're better off doing the date calculation entirely in perl anyway.